# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTimeZone

Tags: php, date, timezone

I'm using this code:

```
$dtzone = @new DateTimeZone($this->session->userdata('timezone'));
$time =  date('r',$this->session->userdata('old_last_login'));
$dtime = new DateTime($time);
@$dtime->setTimeZone($dtzone);
```

It works ok in all browsers except in Firefox where I get message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTimeZone::__construct() 
[<a href='datetimezone.--construct'>datetimezone.--construct</a>]: Unknown or bad timezone ()' 
in /home/example.loc/public_html/application/views/_partials/top.php:7 Stack trace: #0
/home/example.loc/public_html/application/views/_partials/top.php(7): DateTimeZone->__construct('') ...
```

Seems this is the most important part of the error message: **Unknown or bad timezone ()**

I don't understand why its ok in all browsers and why it doesn't work in Firefox.

Timezone is set. e.g. to : **America/Montevideo**

To me it seems that firefox store cookie in some invalid format because when I change code to this:

```
$dtzone = @new DateTimeZone('America/Montevideo');
```

it works.

Comment: try `var_dump($this->session->userdata('timezone'))` when you have the error and see what you get.  Maybe it has `America\/Montevideo` or something like that?  Since that throws an exception, the `@` has no effect, you need to put it in a `try { ... } catch () { }` block.

Comment: So what is `$this->session->userdata('timezone')` at the moment you're trying to instantiate new DateTimeZone object? From the error message it seems that it is null.

Comment: In FF the $this->session->userdata('timezone') is empty value, In other browsers it shows America/Montevideo

Comment: How are you setting `timezone` and is it possible that you don't have this data stored in your FF session? Also, how much data are you storing in your session? Codeigniter stores session data in a cookie, which is usually limited to 4k. Try `var_dump($this->session_all_userdata());` to see what is actually stored in the session.

Comment: in firefox timezone session variable is empty if I run code on my remote server. If I run code on my development machine $this->session->userdata('timezone') contains "America/Montevideo" so it seems to be some issue related to FF and PHP